# Spring framework Freemarker macro layout, nested doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, layout, freemarker

I use spring framework for my web-application and
I have the main layout application.ftl in directory web/WEB-INF/views/layout

```
<#macro layout>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Some content here
    <#nested>
        Some content here
    </body>
    </html></#macro>
```

And have another pages in directory web/WEB-INF/views, 
For example page1.ftl

```
<@layout>This is the page one</@layout>
```

and page 2 ftl.

```
<@layout>This is the page two</@layout>
```

But it doesn't work. My dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
    <import resource="spring/spring-aop.xml" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.birthright.controllers"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="WEB-INF/resources/"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver"
          p:cache="true"
          p:prefix=""
          p:suffix=".ftl"
          p:contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <bean id="freemarkerConfig"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer"
          p:templateLoaderPath="/WEB-INF/views/"
          p:defaultEncoding="UTF-8">
        <property name="templateLoaderPaths">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/views/layout</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="freemarkerSettings">
            <props>
                <prop key="datetime_format">dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss</prop>
                <prop key="number_format">0.######</prop>
                <prop key="url_escaping_charset">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing the macro file into your views?
`<#import "./layout/application.ftl">`

Also if you have views in WEB-INF/views/ directory your templateLoaderPaths should point to that directory, instead of WEB-INF/views/layout. Your config isn't pointing to the correct directory so your views aren't being found. `<value>/WEB-INF/views</value>`